# Nested lists in Lisp comparison

Tags: lisp

I have a function that can produce a list of n-element sublists from a list of elements but I am stuck in filtering out elements that are just permutations of each other. For example, f(A,B) -> ((A, B) (B,A)) is what I get but I just want ((A,B)) since (B,A) is a permutation. Is there a lisp function for this? I don't need the whole answer but a clue would be appreciated, note that A,B need not be atoms but can be string literals and even lists themselves.

I am doing this

```
(let (newlist '())
  (loop :for x in l1 :do
    (loop :for y in l2 :do
      (push (list x y) newlist)))
```

... and I have another function that filters out these duplicates but it is clunky and probs won't scale for large inputs.

Comment: can you show the function that generates permutations? I think it should be possible to generate less lists by keeping the order fixed, which would be more efficient than filtering the output after it is generated

Comment: Im new to lisp so sorry if it seems like an odd function but I am doing this ` (let (newlist '())
    (loop :for x in l1
        :do(loop :for y in l2
                    :do(push (list x y) newlist)
                    ) )` and I have another function that filters out these duplicates but it is clunky and probs won't scale for large inputs

Comment: thanks, I edited the question so that it is easier to understand (you are encouraged to do so as long as you don't change the subject too much)

Answer (score 0):

One interesting function is the (destructive) `pushnew` which pushes an element to a list only if it is not already existent in the set (list).

```
(defun pair-comb (l1 l2 &key (test #'eql) (key #'identity))
  (let ((result '()))
    (loop for x in l1 do 
          (loop for y in l2 do
                (pushnew (list x y) result :test test :key key))
          finally (return result))))
```

When we make the comparison between the elements in a way that it is order-agnostic, we would have the perfect function for us to collect different lists while ruling out the permutations of any of the already collected lists.

This can be done by `#'sort`-ing each list and compare by `#'equalp` or whatever equality function.

```
(pair-comb '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4 5) :test #'equalp :key (lambda (x) (sort x #'<)))
;;=> ((3 5) (3 4) (3 3) (2 5) (2 4) (2 3) (2 2) (1 5) (1 4) (1 3) (1 2) (1 1))
;; well, actually in this case #'eql would do it.
;; when using non-numeric elements, the `#'<` in sort has to be changed!
```